# Maximum for our own data type

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have made my own data type in haskell as:

```
data List a = ListNode a (List a) | ListEnd
```

How can I implement a custom maximum function which finds the maximum of the list for instance:

```
 mymaximum (ListNode 10 ListEnd)
```

should return 10

```
mymaximum (ListNode 20 (ListNode 10 ListEnd))
```

will return 20

Comment: try with recursion with an acumulator

Comment: The most elegant way would be to make `List` implement [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) and use the standard `maximum`, but recursion is ok, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *could* define a recursive function:

```
myMaximum :: Ord a => List a -> a
myMaximum (ListNode a ListEnd) = a
myMaximum (ListNode a b) = max a (myMaximum b)
```

However, a cleaner solution would reuse Haskell's existing [`maximum` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) rather than defining your own:

`maximum :: forall a . (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> a`

For this, you need to define (or, as other commenters have noted, derive) a `Foldable` instance for `List`, e.g.:

```
instance Foldable List where
  foldMap f ListEnd              = undefined
  foldMap f (ListNode x ListEnd) = undefined
  foldMap f (ListNode x r      ) = undefined
```

...which, once completed, will allow you to call `maximum` on `List`s:

```
λ> maximum (ListNode 20 (ListNode 10 ListEnd))
20
```

Comment: You don't even need to _write_ the `Foldable` instance, just use `-XDeriveFoldable`.

Comment: Alternatively, `maximum [x, y]` can be written `max x y` or ``x `max` y``.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on bereal's comment, spracch's answer and leftaroundabout's comment given to it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data List a = ListNode a (List a) | ListEnd
  deriving Foldable
```

And then, similarly,

```
λ> maximum $ ListNode 5 (ListNode 20 (ListNode 10 ListEnd))
20
```